# Time enabled service has different time extent in ArcGIS Online?

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-online, time

I have a time enabled layer that I have published to ArcGIS for Server 10.3

There are times ranging from 5am to 10am (all on one day).
[image]

This flows through to the ArcGIS Server service as expected:
[image]

However, when I then add this same ArcGIS Server service to the embedded map viewer within my ArcGIS Online account, it comes up with the wrong time range by default.  If I change the time slider to the correct time window and choose to increment it in 5 minute intervals (which is how I am successfully doing it within ArcGIS Desktop) it fails to show any data.

[image]

How can I configure this so that ArcGIS Online has the right time extent to match the ArcGIS Server map service,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rookie mistake.  Specifying the timezone fixed the issue for me. ([App](http://s3-ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/languagesofaustralia.com/SimonJacksonFiles/BrisbaneGTFS/gtfs_time.html))

[image]